# How to compare String variables in EL?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el

I have a bean `Mybean` with 2 properties:

```
ArrayList<String> stringArr = {'a','b','c'};
User user; // With 'name' property.
```

I need to display `stringArr` in a `<t:dataList>` as follows:

```html
<t:dataList value="#{MyBean.a}" var="i">
     <!-- Compare user.name bean propery with i. -->
     <c:if test="#{???}"></c:if>
</t:dataList>
```

How can I in `test="#{???}"` compare the `#{user.name}` with var `#{i}` on every iteration? I ultimately need to check if `user.name == i`.

Answer (score 4):

If I don't misread your question you want to output something based on the state of a loop variable, so for instance for an `h:outputText`:

```html
<t:dataList value="#{MyBean.a}" var="i">
  <h:outputText value="#{MyBean.user.name == i ? 'match' : 'no match'}"/>
</t:dataList>
```

This will print `match` if the condition is true and `no match` if not.